# Best way to transfer files from one server to another using a third server

Tags: ssh, copy

Here's the scenario:

```
                   ssh  +------------+
                  +---->|  Server 2  |
 +------------+   |     +------------+
 |  Server 1  +---+
 +------------+   |     +------------+
                  +---->|  Server 3  |
                   ssh  +------------+
```

I have SSH access from `Server 1` to both `Server 2` and `Server 3` (but not from `Server 2` to `Server 3` nor the other way around).

I want to transfer a rather large file from `2` to `3` and would like to know what's the fastest way to do so by having `1` acting as the orchestrator.

**UPDATE**: I do have connectivity between the two servers, just not SSH credentials from/to the servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do the transfer directly between the 2 servers:

on the server you want to transfer to, start nc in listen mode on some random port:

```
ssh dst-server 'exec 1>/tmp/bah; nc -l -p 34001'
```

on the server you want to download from, transfer with nc in client mode. you can use compression to, just create a gzip pipe:

```
ssh source-server 'nc dst-server 34001 < ./bah'
```

you'll find your file in /tmp/bah

Comment: Not if server2 can't make a connection to server3, which is how I read the question. @kolrie explicitly says "by having 1 acting as the intermediary."

Comment: I do have connectivity between the two servers. Added a clarification to the question.

Comment: I read "ssh access"

Comment: Also changed the word from intermediary to orchestrator, to make it fair.

Answer (score 6):

You could use 'scp':

On Server 1 do something like this:

```
scp  user1@server2:/path/filename user3@server3:/path
```

More info with `man scp`.

Comment: this will tranfer the file on the middle server and then upload it to destination server. kind of ... expensive, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It seems my original question was misleading. I can access Server 2 from Server 1 and vice-versa. Just can't SSH connect between the two.

Comment: @malfaux: Yes, it's doubling the transfer. But in most cases, it's just much more quicker than your approach, which I would do for large files or over a slow link.

Comment: @SvenW oh? how is transferring 2x$N GB of data over 2 different links "much more quicker" than transferring $N GB of data over the same link? i'd say it's much more costly, time and money. unless you know he has fiber between s1 and s2 and s1 and s3 and a dial-up link between s2 and s3. is that your argument? I'm just curious what are you thinking. cheers!

Comment: @malfaux: In most cases with a few GB of transfer, the copying would be done with my version of the command before I logged into two computers to initiate a transfer via `nc`. This is moot anyway, because in my networks, when a machine can talk to another via `nc`, it can talk to it via `ssh`.